# JDBI3 reverse of AbstractArgumentFactory.build

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

My MySQL table looks have three columns one long(user_id) another varchar(name) and finally varchar(rules(this is a JSON array as string)). I have integrated JDBI3 recently and I am using its `@BindBean` option. My bean(user class) looks as follows.

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Rule> rules;
}
```

and my rule class looks as follow.

```
public class Rule {
    private long id;
}
```

I have also created an `AbstractArgumentFactory` as follows

```
public class RuleArgumentFactory extends AbstractArgumentFactory<List<Rule>> {

    public RuleArgumentFactory() {
        super(Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    @Override
    protected Argument build(List<Rule> value, ConfigRegistry config) {
        return (position, statement, ctx) -> statement.setString(position, valueToJson());
    }
}
```

I have finally attached the `ArgumentFactory` to handle while performing DB queries. Now when I am doing an update or insert operation like as follows it works well.

```
this.jdbi.useHandle(handle -> {
    handle.registerArgument(new RuleArgumentFactory());
    handle.createUpdate(UPDATE_QUERY)
        .bindBean(User)
        .execute();
});
```

But the problem is when I perform a select query,

```
return this.jdbi.withHandle(handle -> {
    handle.registerArgument(new RuleArgumentFactory());
    return handle.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY)
            .bind(param, paramValue)
            .mapToBean(User.class)
            .findFirst();
});
```

I am unable to get the `User` Object because when JDBI tries to execute the build function. Arguments to the function gets mismatched as they become `(String, ConfigRegistry)` while it is accepting `(List<Rule>, ConfigRegistry)` finally throwing the error `argument type mismatch`. Is there a way where I can serialise the JSON to the `List<Rule>` object. Perhaps something opposite to `build()`.